# django update - update logic of already set mandatory fields

Tags: django, django-models

I have a problem when I update an object. This is the model:

```
class HourRecord(models.Model):
    day_of_work = models.PositiveIntegerField(max_length=1)
    date_of_work = models.DateField(verbose_name='creation date')
    who_worked = models.ForeignKey(User)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='hour_record_set', null=True)

    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, editable=False, related_name='hour_record_creator')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False, verbose_name='creation date')
    modified_by = models.ForeignKey(User, editable=False, related_name='hour_record_modifier')
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)


    def save(self, request):
        if not self.id:
            self.who_worked = request.user
            self.created_by = request.user
        self.modified_by = request.user
        super(HourRecord, self).save()
```

The created_by field should only be set if its a new object. Therefore the "if not self.id:". This worked fine till now.

Till now I updated the object like this:

```
if hrform.is_valid():
            hour_record = hrform.save(commit=False)
            hour_record.save(request)
```

But when I update the model like this I get an error:

```
project = Project.objects.get(id=project_pk)
hr_object = HourRecord(id=hour_record_pk, day_of_work=weekday, date_of_work=date, who_worked=request.user, project=project)
hr_object.save(request)
```

The error message is:

```
Column 'created_by_id' cannot be null
```

Thats strange to me since the created_by column has been already set. I checked it in the database. After this error message when I check again the object is updated and created_by_id is set to null. Actually this is strange. I get an error message + the row is updated.

The second approach is called from within a json data handling view. But I don't think that it has anything to do with it. I think I can circumvent this problem when I reset the created_by_id, but that is not what I want to do, since it corrupts the logic of this created_by field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the issue appears to be that you are explicitly setting the `id` field when you instantiate the HourRecord object:

```
hr_object = HourRecord(id=hour_record_pk,...
```

So when you get to the `save()` method, it checks if it has an ID... and it does, so it doesn't set `who_worked` and `created_by`.

I wonder why you need to set the ID. Normally, you should let the database set it automatically via the autoincrement.

(Not related to your issue, but your `save` method should accept the `force_update` and `force_insert` parameters, and pass them to the super method. The easiest way to do this is to get into the habit of always using `*args, **kwargs` when overriding a method.)

**Edit**: To answer your question of why this doesn't work like an update statement, it's because you're explicitly replacing the old object with a new one. In effect, you're deleting the old db entry and inserting a completely new set of data. There'd be no way for Python to know whether you intended to keep a field's old value, or set it to NULL, for example.

The way to do this, as you have noted, is to get the existing object and updating its attributes explicitly.

Comment: I want to update/overwrite the object. Therefore I give the ID to the model constructor. Is this the wrong approach? I'm following the approach of the django docs: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#explicitly-specifying-auto-primary-key-values

Comment: That's fine, but in that case you will also need to set `created_by` automatically when you instantiate the object, as it won't be done in your `save` method.

Comment: Ok but I'm just wondering why it behaves not like an sql update statement. I'm not an expert in sql either, but I think the update statement only updates the fields provided and leave the others as they are. That is what I would expect. Is there not a django equivalent to this behaviour?

Comment: I think I just have to get the HourRecord object and then modify the values that I want to modify with HourRecord.get_object_or_404(pk=hour_record_pk), then change the fields and then save it. This way I think I getting around my problem. But still I would expect HourRecord(id=hour_record_pk,..) behave different. But there are probably good reasons that it does not behave I would expect it ;-)